# get X509Certificate serial number

Tags: java, security, x509certificate

I need to get serial number of x509 certificate. The result of usage "certificate.getSerialNumber()" differs from the expected. As I see X509 certificate file specs, it should go in following format:

```
    Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
        signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
        signatureValue       BIT STRING  }

   TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
        serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
        signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
        issuer               Name,
        validity             Validity,
        subject              Name,
        subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
        issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                             -- If present, version shall be v2 or v3
        subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                             -- If present, version shall be v2 or v3
        extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                             -- If present, version shall be v3
        }
```

And I couldn't find in the begining of the file the value that is provided by certificate.getSerialNumber() method.

And related question: When trying to display the serial with openssl it takes right value from file but adds '3' after each number.

So my question is: How can I get the stored serial value? And where to read why and how openssl and java modifies this data.

**OPENSSL**

Run with:

```
openssl x509 -serial -noout -inform DER -in mycert.cer
```

Result:

```
serial=3030303031303030303030313030373439323639
```

**JAVA**

Code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("mycert.cer");
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", provider);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(in);
BigInteger serialNum = certificate.getSerialNumber();
System.out.println(serialNum);
```

Output:

```
275106190557734483187066766755592068430195471929
```

**FILE**

And viewing the file, I see:

```
0...0..r.......000010000001007492690
.   *.H..
..
```

which seems to be the serial, provided by openssl but openssl mix it with '3'(after each number).

Comment: For reference, `0x30` is the ASCII code for '0'.  Likewise `0x31` for '1'...all the way up to 0x39.

Comment: There is lots of useful stuff regarding OpenSSL Library on https://zakird.com/2013/10/13/certificate-parsing-with-openssl/ and http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certserial.htm

Comment: [X509 serial number using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582850/x509-serial-number-using-java) provides solution: `.getSerialNumber().toString(16)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ruby and found the answer here in java [X509 serial number using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582850/x509-serial-number-using-java/12583135#12583135)

For those who wants the solution in ruby

```
serial = 275106190557734483187066766755592068430195471929
serial.to_s(16)
```

this will output 3030303031303030303030313030373439323639

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't modify this data. I'd be amazed if openssl did either. Presumably your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: Hello, I modified my question. I know that I am wrong somewhere, please, help me find where. The number from file is required as result.

Comment: OpenSSL is just printing the hex values. '0' is 0x30, '1' is 0x31, etc. No idea what Java is doing, but I can't see all your code from the iPad at the moment, I'll have a proper look tomorrow.

Comment: Your Java code looks OK to me, provided it is reading the same file.

Comment: Yes it is the same file. You can also help voting for this question to make it more markable.