# X509 serial number using java

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, x509, certificate

I need to get some data from X509 certificate.

If I open a certificate file in windows, its showing its serial number in this format.

```
ex. 39 65 70 eb d8 9f 28 20 4e c2 a0 6b 98 48 31 0d
```

The same data I am trying to obtain using java. After get it loaded, I use

```
x509.getSerialNumber();
and result is : 76292708057987193002565060032465481997
```

So what is the difference between both of these ? I want the result as upper one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Windows shows the hexadecimal representation of the serial number, whereas Java returns a `BigInteger` result from [`X509Certificate.getSerialNumber()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSerialNumber%28%29).

To display the `BigInteger` as a hexadecimal value, just call `toString(16)`.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("76292708057987193002565060032465481997");
System.out.println(bi.toString(16));
```

Will output:

```
396570ebd89f28204ec2a06b9848310d
```

Comment: I was also converting it to HEX but My mistake was taking it into  bytes.
i.e. **"76292708057987193002565060032465481997".getBytes();** So I was getting this
3736323932373038303537393837313933303032353635303630303332343635343831393937.
definitely You saved me @Duncan, I was trying for 3 hours...

Answer (score 2):

The first one is hexadecimal value of the certificate.
The other one is decimal.

Now it depends on how you convert the initial certificate bytearray for printing it out.

Lets say this is your certificate:

```java
byte[] cert = { (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0xDD, ..., (byte) 0x00 };
BigInteger certVal = new BigInteger(cert);  
System.out.println("And result is  (hex): " + certVal.toString(16));
```